ParticleSystem freezes the game on first instantiation
I have a simple class with a ParticleSystem prefab:
public class ParticleEffects : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] public ParticleSystem starExplosion;
}

And I instantiate it like this:
public void CatCollision(Cat cat)
{
    ParticleSystem particleSystem = Instantiate(particleEffects.starExplosion, cat.transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
    Destroy(particleSystem.gameObject, particleSystem.main.duration + particleSystem.main.startLifetime.constantMax);
}

This works, but the first time CatCollision is called, the game freezes momentarily, apparently to instantiate the particle system the first time. Obviously I don't want the pause. Is there a way to pre-instantiate it or something? How is this generally handled to avoid the first-time pause?

There are multiple ways how to handle this or reasons why it could freeze. You could use a similar approach to object pooling if you need to create a lot of them (instead of instantiating, enabling/ disabling them). Even if you need it only once (for GameOver explosion), you could have it just disabled in the scene and enable it on need. The freeze might comefrom too big of a texture/ image used in the particle system.

A couple of other candidates could be: compiling a shader/variant that wasn't needed until now, or allocating a big buffer of memory for the particles (and possibly triggering a garbage collection pass if there wasn't enough contiguous memory available already). Do you notice the freeze if the particle system spawning is the first thing that happens in your game? Is your max particle count as small as you can make it for the effect you want?
